# .length переменной обнуляется

Tags: javascript

Пишу окно ввода для калькулятора - ограничиваю 15 по длине

```
window.onkeydown = function (num) {
    if ( Screen_total.length < '15' ) {
        if ( keys[num.keyCode] == 'backspace' ) {
            Screen_total = Screen_total/10;
            Screen_total = Screen_total - (Screen_total%1);
            toScreen(Screen_total);
            console.log('Длина:' + Screen_total.length);
        } else {
            console.log(keys[num.keyCode] + ' (клавой)');
            if ( Screen_total != '' ) {
                Screen_total = Screen_total + keys[num.keyCode];
            } else {
                Screen_total = keys[num.keyCode];
            }
            console.log('Длина: ' + Screen_total.length);
            toScreen(Screen_total);
        }
    }
}
```

1. Если оставляю ограничение до 15, то после первого backspace все виснет, и цифры не вводятся и backspace уже не работает
2. Если убираю ограничение, то все работает, но ограничения о уже нет...

Comment: Что в функции `toScreen`? И можно объект `keys` добавить?

Comment: function toScreen(Scr) {
  // Выводим все набранное на экран калькулятора
  document.getElementById('calc_screen_input').value = Scr;
 }

Comment: Вот: var keys = {"48":"0","49":"1","50":"2","51":"3","52":"4","53":"5","54":"6","55":"7","56":"8","57":"9","8":"backspace"};

Comment: В общем После любых арифметических действий Screen_total.length становится undefined

Answer (score 2):

У вас проблемы с приведением типов и немного с самой логикой условия

```js
const keys = {"48":"0","49":"1","50":"2","51":"3","52":"4","53":"5","54":"6","55":"7","56":"8","57":"9","8":"backspace"};
let Screen_total = "";
function toScreen(Scr) {};

window.onkeydown = function (num) {
  if ( keys[num.keyCode] === 'backspace' ) {
    Screen_total = Screen_total/10;
    Screen_total = String(Screen_total - (Screen_total%1));
    toScreen(Screen_total);
    console.log(Screen_total, 'Длина:' + Screen_total.length);
  } else if ( Screen_total.length < '15' ) {
    console.log(keys[num.keyCode] + ' (клавой)');
    if ( Screen_total != '' ) {
      Screen_total = String(Screen_total + keys[num.keyCode]);
    } else {
      Screen_total = String(keys[num.keyCode]);
    }
    console.log('Длина: ' + Screen_total.length);
    toScreen(Screen_total);
  }
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, все заработало ! Сейчас буду разбираться ...